# Pattern Matching c#

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

Lets say I have a text file with the line below within it. I want to take both values within the quotations by matching between (" and "), so that would be I retreive ABC and DEF and put them in a string list or something, what's the best way of doing this? It's so annoying

If EXAMPLEA("ABC") AND EXAMPLEB("DEF")

Comment: Did you tried anything? I don't think so. Please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: Are there any complex variants to possible strings? Is there any escaping mechanism (to e.g. allow `"` characters to appear in strings)?

Comment: You mentioned regex in the tags - that's a good way, try it!

Comment: Please show us at least a tiny bit of effort. `It's so annoying` tells me you didn't even try to do it.

Comment: your problem has been solved..y dont you accept the ans!you can accept the ans by checking the right mark beside the ans

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a case where the value between the double quotes can not contain escaped double quotes might work like this:

```
 var text = "If EXAMPLEA(\"ABC\") AND EXAMPLEB(\"DEF\")";
 Regex pattern = new Regex("\"[^\"]*\"");

 foreach (Match match in pattern.Matches(text))
 {
     Console.WriteLine(match.Value.Trim('"'));
 }
```

But this is only one of the many ways you could do it and maybe not the smartest way out there. Try something yourself!

Answer (score 0):

Best way...

```
List<string> matches=Regex.Matches(File.ReadAllText(yourPath),"(?<="")[^""]*(?="")")
                          .Cast<Match>()
                          .Select(x=>x.Value)
                          .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This pattern should do the trick:

\"([^"]*)\"

```
        string str = "If EXAMPLEA(\"ABC\") AND EXAMPLEB(\"DEF\")";
        MatchCollection matched = Regex.Matches(str, @"\""([^\""]*)\""");
        foreach (Match match in matched)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
        }
```

Note that the quotation marks are doubled in the actual code in order to escape them.  And the code refers to group [1] to get just the part inside the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<string> matches =
    from Match match
    in Regex.Matches(File.ReadAllText(filepath), @"\""([^\""]*)\""")
    select match.Groups[1].Value;
```

Others already posted some answers, but my takes into account that you just want `ABC` and `DEF` in your example, without quotation marks and save it in a `IEnumerable<string>`.